# How to compensate for padding on 100% width input text fields?

Tags: html, css, textinput

I have placed padding left and right on my input text field so that that text inside of the field does not butt right up to the left and right side of the field. This is a standard UI design practice, as you know. The issue I'm facing is I want my input text field to have a 100% width so that it fills the inside of a div, in effect I have no defined a specific pixel value for this input text field, as it is filling the surrounding div container.  How would I compensate my width for the padding I place on this field? Do I need to manually to decrease my width, let's say to 93%, until it achieves the same result?

Comment: Could we see simplified example code?

Comment: If you don't need to support IE7 (or previous), you can use [`box-sizing: border-box`](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).